# Swift: How to create couchDb database and insert data to it in offline?

Tags: database, swift, couchdb

I am developing an app, which is in swift language. 
In my app I want to use couchdb database for storing and sync purpose.
which will work offline too.

so, how to create couchDB database first and then insert data in that database, so that my application use that database as local storage.

Please provide some guide line or an help or comment or sample code to performed that operation 
Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

I think what you should look at is Couchbase Lite which will allow you to do CRUD operations with a native embedded database in Swift, and replicate that to CouchDB at a later time.

Conceptually what's going on here is you can consider CouchDB Replication to be a protocol unto itself, supported by a variety of implementations (check out Pouchdb also for example)

Comment: I don't want how to make HTTP request in my project. what I want to know, how to use couchDB as local database in my project like sqlite.

Comment: I apologise if I didn't understand but HTTP *is* the way you make CRUD operations using Couchdb., have a look at the `Databases` & `Documents` sections of the Core API link I posted in my answer.

Comment: I am done to create a couchDB database. I am run the sample code on github site but, the code is run only on simulator it can't run on ipad device. when I am going to run it on ipad the 'linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)' error was occured. now what I am do?

Comment: @PallaviNikumbh usually this means that you are trying to link the x86 (Simulator) libs in an ARM (device) build, check your project config.   This however is to do with Xcode not specific to Couchbase/couchdb, so if you are unable to get the build working I would suggest accepting this answer (if it has been helpful) and asking a new question including your verbose build output.

Comment: Ah ya, but I can't understand what was actually you said that, Please can you elaborate your answer.